# "Oughtn't to" and the past tense of it

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, semi-modals

Is the sentence below grammatically ok? Or something is wrong with it?

1. They oughtn't to have worked harder.

Or

2. They ought to have worked harder.

Can we use past simple from ought - oughted? I found it somewhere but it seems to be awkward...

3. They oughted to work harder.

Comment: "*Ought" is **oughkward**. Should have used **should**. "They should have worked harder".

Comment: @WeatherVane  You oughtn't to say that.  Some are perfectly comfortable with "ought".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not a native speaker, in all of my years of experience, I've never seen **they oughted to work harder**. I don't think the past tense form of the verb **ought** even exists. Just like there's no past tense form of the modal **must**. I'd say that if you want to express **ought** in the past, you would simply say **had**. And to be perfectly honest, **ought** is not used that often in spoken English. You'll most likely hear it used as part of set phrases like **you ought not judge**, **you ought not to have done that**, et cetera. There's not a whole lot of expressions like that in English though.

PS: Notice that the grammar in the two examples with **ought** that I gave you is a little bit inconsistent. In the second example, there is a **to** while the first one doesn't have it. And that's the point that I'm trying to make: **ought** is an old-style verb that has survived in modern English in the form of idiomatic expressions whose grammatical structures may seem antiquated and irregular.

Comment: The reason that "ought" doesn't have a past tense is that it is the (obsolete) past tense of "owe". An expression like "You ought to do that" is derived from the past subjunctive in Old English, from the idea that you owe a duty.  There is no past tense form of ought.

Comment: It's good to know that. But today I think "ought" has a sense of a present-tense verb.

Comment: Yes, It acts like a present tense modal. Compare "should" (which is also a past tense, of "shall")

Comment: Thanks! What about the sentence number 1. Is it ok?

Comment: I guess, technically speaking it's correct.